# Facebook Suspicious Login work around from iPad

Tags: facebook, ipad, authentication, upload

I am not sure if anyone has ran into the problem but it is really bugging me and affecting our uploading from our iPad to facebook.

I have a local server running XAMMP with a gallery of images displayed via a local web page. These images are from our Photobooths and automatically get added into the gallery when a photo is taken in the booth.

These can then be accessed on the local network via the iPad. Users can then login to facebook and share this images.

Because this is a shared iPad being used by multiple users, is there any way of getting users to login without having to answer security questions?? It used to be fine but now Facebook says the login is suspicious as it does to recognise the device.

I have created an App to post the photos to facebook through the Facebook Development site and it works perfectly from my account and many users, but some seem to get the suspicious login attempt and have to identify friends and date of birth etc.

Is there a correct way to do this?

Thank you Richard.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a correct way to do this?

What you are experiencing *is* the “correct” way.

Facebook offers this as a security feature – a user can add his devices to his list of “known” devices, from which he will be able to login straight away, and have to answer additional security questions when logging in from a different, “unknown” device.

If users have this feature enabled, they should not be surprised by this happening in your scneario. It’s what they explicitly want, and they’re getting it.

So you should in no way try to mess with that, just because *you* might think this to be “uncool” or a “nuisance” – it’s not, it’s a feature offering extended security that the user wants and has explicitly chosen.